# invalid target type casting: red-context

Tags: red, red-system

I am using the `--red-only` switch with the verbosity set to 2 to compile a very simple Red program to its Red/System equivalent.  The program is:

```
Red []

red-load: func [source  [file! url! string! binary!]] [
    load source
]
```

It produces a certain amount of output, which I redirected to a file.  My goal was to add a Red/System header to this and build it.

After getting rid of some commentary lines, the next barrier is that this code had not expanded at least some macros, so I had to add a `#include` for [runtime/macros.reds](https://github.com/red/red/blob/1fc8c7875c5d777c5097ce1322ff21f60136a505/runtime/macros.reds).  But then I got this error in the expansion of one of those (macros TO_CTX):

```
*** Compilation Error: invalid target type casting: red-context! 
*** in file: %/home/hostilefork/Projects/red/embedme.reds 
*** in function: f_modulo
*** at line: 11 
*** near: (as red-context! ((as series! ctx15/value) + 1))
```

I've seen `red-context!` and some other `red-*!` datatypes used in the Red runtime code...when Red/System needs to talk about values it gets from Red.  But they are not mentioned [in the Red/System spec](http://static.red-lang.org/red-system-specs-light.html).  Can they be used in ordinary Red/System code, or is there something "special" allowing them only internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verbosity 2 is not the right setting if you want to have a complete Red/System output, the verbosity should be set to 3 (`-v 3`). I never tried to actually compile such output, so I am not sure that it will work anyway. The `--red-only?` option purpose is for debugging the Red/System output from the high-level Red compiler.

The `red-*!` definitions are macros over Red internal structures, they are not part of Red/System. They are defined in the Red [runtime library](https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/runtime/datatypes/structures.reds).

Comment: Thanks, it worked with minor tweaks.  In this case, just the content of **output:** with search and replace `~%` => `~percent`, `~//` => `~slashslash`, `~/` => `~slash`...then and add an `#include` up top for `red.reds`.